# How to check if update is available from my installed app?

Tags: androidx, package-managers, android-update-app

I create a list of my installed apps using PackageManager, But I want to know if the app has a new version on it so I can update it from that list.
Any idea?

this is the detail I got from PackageManager

```
Log.v("/asd/", "AppName:"+modelMyAppsInstalledApps.get(i).getAppname());
Log.v("/asd/", "AppPackageName:"+modelMyAppsInstalledApps.get(i).getApppackagename());
Log.v("/asd/", "AppVersionName:"+modelMyAppsInstalledApps.get(i).getAppversionname());
Log.v("/asd/", "AppVersionCode:"+modelMyAppsInstalledApps.get(i).getAppversioncode());
Log.v("/asd/", "AppIcon:"+modelMyAppsInstalledApps.get(i).getAppicon().toString());
```

Comment: Maybe this?
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Comment: @Sk1X1, unfortunately, that was an update availability from your own app, not another app